# How to window.location.hash-change the location, then run a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, hashchange

I have a function, say

```
function runSomething()
{
   alert("hello");
}
```

I have `window.onhashchange = runSomething;`
And in my code, I call `window.location.hash = "#processsection"`

runSomething runs, however it runs before the page does to #processsection...how can I get it to only run AFTER I am on #processsection?

Comment: What do you mean with "AFTER"? After the UI scrolled to that anchor?

Comment: yes! after JQuery Mobile has scrolled there! Basically I am not seeing whatever runSomething is doing until it has finished!

Comment: In other words, it does some stuff and I am not seeing it because it doesnt go to that section until it has finished

Comment: They do, but it's late in the night and you gave them only 12 minutes. [This is not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128548/183280) a hotline :)

Comment: is #processsection a page? i.e `<div data-role="page" id="processsection">`. Give us more code so we can see the bigger picture. Or if you can make a jsfiddle illustrating the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your scenario I would probably use an if condition to check if that div or body (whichever applies) is animating aka. scrolling. Here's an untested, rough idea.

```
function runSomething() {        
    if ($('body').is(':animated') {
        $('body').queue(function() {
            alert("hello");
        });
    } else {
        alert("hello");
    }
}
```